# Help with homework and bijections

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let A,B respectvely denote the even and odd integers (remember, 0 is even).
(a) Is there a bijection from A to B?
(b) Is there a bijection from Z to A?

I think these might be very basic questions but my book doesn't have the answers in it and I'm not sure about the "Is there" part, so can someone help me, please?

Comment: kindly include your thoughts and attempts.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh A to B is onto because all odd integers are even numbers +1 but I'm not sure if they are 1-to-1 because it also could be the even numbers -1, I don't know if when it asks "Is there a bijection from A to B?" it is asking if I can come up with one function that is bijective or if there is a specific way of making a function and this function is bijective .

Comment: The hardest thing for people who are new to math is probably getting used to strict definitions. I suggest that you hone your understanding of fundamental concepts such as bijections etc. A one-to-one function doesn't mean there is only one function, it just means that given a function there aren't different arguments that get mapped to the same value. So it's true that both x+1 and x-1 map even numbers to odd, but each of these functions is injective (one-to-one), and also surjective, and therefore bijective.

Comment: More about precision: notice Sean Roberson's answer where he explains that "is there" means precisely what it says, and nothing more. This is a good example why clearly understanding the exact intentions and definitions is important. In this example, it just so happens that sometimes in math you can prove something exists, but you can't find it explicitly. You might be able to prove that a series converges, but you would have no idea to what value. So "is there" is definitely different to "give an example of", although the latter can serve as an answer to the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "is there" can be thought of "Can you construct...?" This is an existence question, and you are asked to see if such mappings exist.

Spoiler alert:

> There are.

Comment: "Can you construct...?" Thank you so much !!!